# One-click Download files from webform submission

Tags: 7, webforms, files

I have content editors who need a 'one click' download solution for all the files uploaded with a given webform submission. FTP is not an option.

Does anyone know of any solution for this?

Comment: Is a mail to the content editors with the files as attachments an option? Then https://drupal.org/comment/6320046#comment-6320046 could give you a hint.

Comment: A hacky workaround would be using some downloader plugin in your browser, e.g. "DownThemAll" for Firefox... With this plugin you can easily download all the files visible on the webform submissions page...